# ESP8266 Send Data To a Website bad request

Tags: apache, arduino, esp8266

I want to send some text to Apache Server, but i get some errors
I'm a newbie in ESP2866.

I can't find the reasons.

I received: "400 Bad request"......**.Request header field is missing ':'** separator:
then  i received some errors:
**Wrong syntax....**

I send following header to server:

> POST /receiver.php HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: 192.168.1.9
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Content-Length: 20
>
> temp=35

I use this code in Arduino:

```
 String cmd,aaa;
 aaa="temp="+35;
 cmd= "POST /temp.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
 cmd+="Host: 192.168.1.9\r\n";
 cmd+="Content-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: "+aaa.length();
 cmd+="\r\n\r\n"+aaa+"\r\n\r\n";


 Serial.print("Sending to Server: ");
 aaa= "AT+CIPSEND=";
 aaa+=cmd.length();
 aaa+="\r\n";

 Serial.println(sendData(aaa, 1000));
 Serial.println(sendData(cmd,2000));

 delay(1000);
```

This is sendData function:

```
String sendData(String command, const int timeout)
{
  String response = "";

  esp.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

  long int time = millis();

  while ( (time + timeout) > millis())
  {
    while (esp.available())
    {
      // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
      char c = esp.read(); // read the next character.
      response += c;
    }
  }
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Request Header Field is missing" error is reported by the server. It looks like you are missing the "From" and "User-Agent" headers.

The "Wrong Syntax" error is likely generated by the ESP8266, I am currently experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
aaa="temp="+35;
```

I think here is the issue. 35 is integer here. Thats why the value of aaa is some weird characters instead of "temp=35". And so Server is not catching the variable.